# How to add extract characters from a string then add them in C++?

Tags: c++, string, binary

I'm currently working on an assignment for my CS250 class (Discrete Structures). I have to implement a full adder into my application. I've managed to complete all that. However, i was only able to do it when i manually give it TRUTH TABLE values. The idea is, i need to add 2 strings consisting of binary digits. for example:

```
std::string binaryStringOne = "10101010";
std::string binaryStringTwo = "10001";
```

I have to add those strings together and output its representation in binary. Now my question is this, how do i approach adding those binary strings?

My train of though was this:

1. Start by obtaining the last index value from both strings ["0","1"]
2. convert each string value ["0","1"] into int's
3. insert them into FullAdder Function (which has been completed)
4. keep the carry value, move to the next index and add (including the carry ref)

That is the overall approach. How would i approach this in code?
Want me to post the other functions on here? Please let me know, i dont think they are needed but if anyone wants to see it for reference, i'll post it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You simply put the code you described into a `for` loop. It would probably simplify things if you extend the shorter string to the length of the longer one by adding leading zeroes.

Comment: You "approach this in code" by reading the documentation for `std::string` which explains how to access and extract parts of string, then use what you've learned to implement your program.

Comment: @Barmar The idea is that the application will ask the user for 2 different binary string inputs. The instructor said that she will be using different size strings, but they will not exceed 8 digits long. So my questions is this, how can i extend the shorter string? I know i can test for length of both strings and compare them to determine which is the shortest. Once i determine which is the shortest, is it simply a matter of concat a bunch of 0 until the length == that of the other string? Or is there a diff approach.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yeah your right i should read the std::string documentation but the truth is that documentation isn't written well for beginners. Some of the documentation can be a bit difficult to understand. I think we learn best by example. Most examples i've seen include concepts of c++ that seem to advance (templates, tuples, etc.)

Comment: Post your code and ask specific questions.  As a hint, you don't need the int conversion.  You can just "add" single characters because you know they will always be '1' or '0'.  Also, if you have a std::string, you can grab an individual character using brackets: mystr[5] will get you the 6th character in the string.  Also, more importantly, you can use iterators which are returned by begin() and end() member functions.

Comment: @AnonMail Thanks, i'll look into it right now. I realize that i need to convert to int, to check that the string doesnt contain any nonNumberCharacters. Yeah i realize that i can use a for loop to iterate through each index in a string, then decrement until i reach the last character in the string (adding from right to left). I've never used begin() and end(), i'll look into it. Thanks

Comment: @JonathanVazquez the only valid characters are '0' and '1' so you can check that - no need to convert to int.

Comment: @AnonMail yeah i got it working. Thank you for your time.